# Find elements in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am in learnign stage of c#.

I want to get all the labels added in the TableLayoutPanel.

```
Control c2 = this.ReportTable.GetControlFromPosition(col,row+1);

Trace.WriteLine(c2.GetType());
if (c2.GetType().Equals(typeof(TableLayoutPanel)))
{
    // Put loop to iterate.  
}
```

ReportTable is also `TableLayoutPanel`. `c2.GetType()` is giving `TableLayoutPanel`. I am not able to apply `RowCount` method on `c2.GetType().RowCount`

Please help me to iterate inside the `TableLayoutPanel` which is inside other `TableLayoutPanel`  with other elements

Comment: @Alex : thanks Alex . I think you havnt read the question description carefully. I know how to interate in TableLayoutPanel . I am not able to iterate iterate inside the TableLayoutPanel1 which is inside TableLayoutPanel with other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind, I figured out. I was suppose to do TypeCasting to Control

```
Control c2 = this.ReportTable.GetControlFromPosition(col,row+1);
                                  Trace.WriteLine(c2.GetType());
                                  if (c2.GetType().Equals(typeof(TableLayoutPanel)))
                                  {
                                      TableLayoutPanel tp = (TableLayoutPanel)c2;

                                      // get all labels in table  
                                      foreach(Control ctr in tp.Controls){
                                          Trace.WriteLine(ctr .GetType());
                                      }

                                  }
```